# In flow, dependent picklist span the entire page unlike a normal picklist

Tags: visual-workflow, dependent-picklist

Basically title. Is there a way to get around this? It’s horribly inconsistent.

[image: Example of dependent picklist spanning the entire page length while a regular picklist does not.]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include details of how to reproduce your issue, and ideally a screenshot showing the issue.

Comment: Hey David, I attached an example of my issue. The dependent picklist in a flow is not formatabble and spans the entire page despite the options within the picklist being short words. It doesn’t line up with a picklist at all.